# Trying to create snipping tool using PyAutoGUI but can't capture left mouse click and drag coordinates

Tags: python

I am trying to create a snipping tool, but using pyautogui to capture the screenshot via the user left clicking and dragging the mouse over the area of the screen they wish to capture. I am currently struggling with capturing the start and end coordinates of the left mouse click and drag.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pyautogui

# Get the starting point of the mouse click and drag
print("Click and drag to select the region for screenshot...")
# Wait for the left mouse button to be pressed


# Get the starting coordinated of the left mouse click
start_x, start_y = pyautogui.position()


# Get the end point of the mouse click and drag
end_x, end_y = pyautogui.position()


# Calculate the region dimensions
width = abs(end_x - start_x)
height = abs(end_y - start_y)


# MAC Scaling
pixelRatio = pyautogui.screenshot().size[0]/pyautogui.size().width
top_left_x_Raw = start_x * pixelRatio
top_left_y_Raw = start_y * pixelRatio
width_Raw = width * pixelRatio
height_Raw = height * pixelRatio


# Capture the screen region
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(top_left_x_Raw, top_left_y_Raw, width_Raw, height_Raw))
```

I was thinking about using pynput, but I'm not sure if that is the right route. Thank you for the help!